# How to get a dictionary of dictionaries from a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary

I can't figure out how to create a dictionary of dictionaries for how many fruit I bought for several days.

Given a text file that looks like this

```
0    apple
0    orange
1    apple
1    apple
1    strawberry
2    orange
```

The first column is which day the fruit what bought on, and the second is which fruit was bought on that day.

I want to return a dictionary of dictionaries, where the keys are the days, and the value is another dictionary that keeps track of how many of that fruit was bought on that day.

```
{0: {'apple': 1, 'orange': 1, 'strawberry': 0}, 1: {'apple': 2, 'orange': 0, 'strawberry': 1}, 2: {'apple': 0, 'orange': 1, 'strawberry': 0}}
```

Im trying to do this without list comprehension or any imports, as I don't quite understand those. Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you show anything you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have a pretty naive solution without imports and list comprehensions.

```py
final = {}

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    prev = None
    for line in f.readlines():
        key, value = line.split()
        if prev == None:
            prev = key
            d = {'apple': 0, 'orange': 0, 'strawberry': 0}
        elif prev != key:
            final[int(prev)] = d
            prev = key
            d = {'apple': 0, 'orange': 0, 'strawberry': 0}

        d[value] = d.get(value, 0)+1
    final[int(prev)] = d

print(final)
```

All I did is created a temporary inner dictionary, then updated it until next value is not reached, then if next value is reached then I have added the previous dictionary to the final one.
Output:

```
{0: {'apple': 1, 'orange': 1, 'strawberry': 0}, 1: {'apple': 2, 'orange': 0, 'strawberry': 1}, 2: {'apple': 0, 'orange': 1, 'strawberry': 0}}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much. How would I do this if there were more columns? Ones that I didnt need to use.

Comment: well if it has more columns then you can split each line into a list and then consider only the necessary columns

Comment: Oh, just noticed that the second day is missing in your output. How can it be added?

Comment: I am sorry for the inconveniences caused. I have added `final[int(prev)] = d` after the loop because if you didn't do the same then the last day value won't get added

Comment: Fantastic! If you have the time, I would also love to know how to identify the right column if many others were added. But if not, thank you anyways for the great help!

Comment: well a `try except`  block might help you, or you might consider spliting each line to a list and `if len(new_list) > 2` then more than 2 columns are present

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be made quite a bit simpler using the [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) classes. You want a dictionary where the day number maps to a `Counter` of the fruits for that day.

```py
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

result = defaultdict(Counter)

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        day, fruit = line.split()
        day = int(day)
        result[day][fruit] += 1
```

Using `defaultdict` and `Counter` saves you from having to test whether the key exists and set an initial value when it doesn't. I don't recommend avoiding imports just for the sake of it, but if you really want a "pure" solution then the above code roughly translates to:

```py
result = dict()

with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        day, fruit = line.split()
        day = int(day)
        if day not in result:
            result[day] = dict()
        if fruit not in result[day]:
            result[day][fruit] = 0
        result[day][fruit] += 1
```

Comment: This is great! Do you know how it can be done without any imports?

Comment: I've edited to give a solution without imports, but I do recommend getting used to using them. They aren't advanced or more difficult to use or learn.

Comment: Those this outputs the fruits with zero count?

Comment: They won't output when you print it, but if you use the `Counter` solution to get `result[0]['strawberry']`, the result will be 0 because no strawberries were added for that day. Otherwise you'll need some extra loop to go through and add the missing keys to each dictionary.